# Don't fire mouseenter event on parent

Tags: jquery, nested, event-listener, mouseenter

For tags (`td`, `p`, `li`) that contain text, I added a `data-id` attribute. When hovering over a tag that has a `data-id` attribute, the button needs to be displayed. Everything works fine, except when the tags are nested, for example:

```
<li aria-level="1" data-id="66389178">
  <p data-id="11168609">text</p>
</li>
```

This example displays two buttons, one for the parent and one for the child. I added `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` but that doesn't work for `td`. Here is the code itself:

```
$('[data-id]').mouseenter(function (e) {
  GodObj.btnadd = $('<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-note-tag">' +
    '<i class=\'fa fa-commenting\' aria-hidden=\'true\'></i>' + '</button>');

  $(this).append(GodObj.btnadd);
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}).mouseleave(function () {
  $(GodObj.btnadd).remove();
});
```

Example when two buttons are drawn:

```
<td aria-level="1" data-id="66389170">
  <p data-id="11168601">...</p>
</td>
```

Content is added by users through the editor on the site, so there is no strict rule for the level of nesting of tags into each other.

**How to make the button render only once or for parent or child elements?**

[image]

Comment: Which one should be triggered: parent or child?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the main thing is that someone is one, and not both at once

Comment: Have a look if this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/2anfL9j6/

Comment: @Shikkediel, It looks like it really works! Many thanks for the help! Here's what happened in the end. Add your own option to the answers so I can vote for it 
https://jsfiddle.net/wolf_den/2dn1kare/

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`:

```js
            $('[data-id]').mouseenter(function (e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                GodObj.btnadd = $('<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-note-tag">' +
                    '<i class=\'fa fa-commenting\' aria-hidden=\'true\'></i>' +
                    '</button>');
                $(this).append(GodObj.btnadd);
            }).mouseleave(function () {
                $(GodObj.btnadd).remove();
            });
```

Comment: Alas this doesn't work for td. As I understand it, the point is that td and its child p have different sizes

Comment: added a link to the screenshot of the question to make it clearer what it is about